# Change css font-weight upon click

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new to css + html and am coding my first website. I have a navigation menu setup inside a div, but I want to change the font-weight of the clicked text from lighter to bold when the user clicks on an item in it (text). Please can you tell me how to do this?

Here is my code so far:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>...</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background" />
        <div id="navigation" class="navigationPlaceholder">
            <div id="navigationText">
                <ul>
                    iOS
                    Blog
                    About
                    Contact
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: XCode can you clarify a little more ? So when they click on a navigation item you want it to change font weight? To signify that's the section they are looking at? Also if i may suggest instead of using breaks use an unordered list to create your navigation, it a cleaner approach and you have more control over the items.

Comment: Thanks, I have upgraded my code to use `<ul>`! Thats exactly what I would like to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a click event listener each navigation item and change its `font-weight` style.

First, start by using an unordered list for your nav

```
<div id="navigationText">
    <ul>
        <li>iOS</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then, place this script block just before the closing `</body>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nav = document.getElementById('navigationText');

var navItems = nav.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
    navItems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    }, false);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, where would I put this?! <noob excuse>As I said above, I am new to html + css</noob excuse> Would it go in the head tags?

Comment: Thanks, my only problem now is that upon clicking on the text, all of the text in the divs are bold. How can I prevent this?

Comment: @XCodeDev Isn't that what you wanted? Perhaps you should revise your question

Comment: Sorry, I have revised the question, I only wanted the selected text in that div to have it's font weight changed.

Comment: It doesn't work at all now. I have an bullet pointed list and upon a click, it's fontWeight doesn't change. Edit--- You missed out an 's' off of the navItems[] array.

Comment: @XCodeDev Oops, there was a typo. I had `navItem[i]` instead of `navItems[i]`

Answer (score 0):

here you have an example, you should do the same wih your div:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function displayResult()
   {
   document.getElementById("p1").style.fontWeight="900";
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p id="p1">This is some text.</p>
  <br />
  <button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Change font weight</button>
 </body>
</html>
```